# What would be the disadvantage of creating an array of really big size on 64 bit systems?

Tags: c++, c, linux, x86-64, mmap

Operating systems like Linux work on the principle of Copy-on-write, so even if you are allocating an array of say 100 GB, but only use upto 10GB, you would only be using 10 GB of memory. So, what would be the disadvantage of creating such a big array? I can see an advantage though, which is that you won't have to worry about using a dynamic array, which would have the cost of reallocations.

Comment: I'm not sure copy-on-write is relevant to your ability to allocate 100GB.

Comment: Possible disadvantage: getting OOM-killed without being able to debug the cause?

Comment: Why not? Basically when you are allocating 100 GB, you are only occupying an adress space, which is plenty on a 64 bit system. Copy-on-write means you are not actually using the memory until you touch it.

Comment: So you used a clever trick to save yourself dynamic allocation overhead by relying on the OS to do dynamic allocation?

Comment: No, I'm just asking from a theoretical perspective.

Comment: This would require a very big page table, which has limits in most OSs

Comment: @pythonic: "Why not?" Because that's just not how real Linuxes work. They usually *overcommit*, and the allocation only results in a new page mapping being created *when you access it*. (It's at that *time of access* that COW becomes relevant.)

Comment: Sorry but the memory allocation is not done in RAM? Basically you cannot allocate such an amount of memory for the array. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Unless you really need 100GB of continuous memory for a single purpose you will need some way to manage that memory. That is, an allocator.

Comment: Another problem (not mentioned yet by answers) is that you reduce your ability to detect bugs (e.g. dodgy pointers and bad array indexes) because there's a higher chance that they'll hit the huge array instead of causing a `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: Another problem (also not mentioned) is that you can't really free the pages after they allocated if they're no longer being used. This means that for some cases you might only be using a fraction of the huge array at a time, but because it's a different fraction at different times you end up leaking memory everywhere.

Comment: Finally; despite these problems the idea can work in limited circumstances. I use "sparse arrays" (as I like to call them) heavily in a micro-kernel; where I can control overcommit behaviour and (when memory is needed elsewhere) can scan the array/s for "allocated but no longer in actual use" pages and free them.

Comment: @pythonic - copy-on-write has nothing to do with the behavior here. Copy on write means that some page is mapped into your process, with read bit set and write bit unset, and the entire contents are copied if you write. It is used, for example, for CoW file mappings and fork and so on. What you are referring to is lazy page allocation. It doesn't involve a copy and the pages aren't mapped in at all. Only a VMA is set up and then when you access the page, you get a page fault and the kernel maps in a new zeroed page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main disadvantage is that by doing this you are making a strong assumption about how exactly the standard library allocators<sup>1</sup> and the underlying Linux allocators work. In fact, the allocators and underlying system do not always work as you mention.

Now, you mentioned "copy on write", but what you are likely really referring to is the combination of lazy page population and [overcommit](https://www.etalabs.net/overcommit.html). **Depending on the configuration**, it means that any memory you allocate but don't touch may not count against memory limits and may not occupy physical memory.

The problem is that this often may not work. For example:

- Many allocators have modes where they touch the allocated memory, e.g., in debug mode to fill it out with a known pattern to help diagnose references to uninitialized memory. Most allocators touch at least a few bytes before your allocated region to store metadata that can be used on deallocation. So you are making a strong assumption about allocator behavior that is likely to break.
- The Linux overcommit behavior is [totally configurable](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting). In practice many server-side Linux users will disable it in order to reduce uncertainty and unrecoverable problems related to the OOM killer. So your claim that Linux behaves lazily is only true in for some overcommit configuration and false for others.
- You might assume that memory is being committed in 4K chunks and adjust your algorithm around that. However, systems have different page sizes: 16K and 64K are not uncommon as base page sizes, and x86 Linux systems by default have [transparent huge pages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/transhuge.txt) enabled, so you may actually be getting 2,048K pages without realizing it! In this case you may end up committing nearly the entire array, depending on your access pattern.
- As mentioned in the comments, the "failure mode" for this type of use is pretty poor. You think you'll only use a small portion of the array, but if you do end up using more than the system can handle, at best you may get a signal to your application on some random access to a new page, but more like the oom killer will just kill some other random process on your machine.

---

<sup>1</sup> Here I'm assuming you are using something like `malloc` or `new` to allocate the array, since you didn't mention `mmap`ing it directly or anything.

Comment: No, you didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Real-world operating systems don't simply allow your program to access all memory available - they enforce quotas.   So a 64-bit operating system, running on hardware with enough physical memory, will simply refuse to allocate all that memory to any program.    This is even more true if your operating system is virtualised (e.g. some hypervisor hosts two or more operating systems on the same physical platform - the hypervisor enforces quotas for each hosted operating system, and one of them will enforce quotas for your program).

Attempting to allocate a large amount of memory is therefore, practically, an effective way to maximise likelihood that the operating system will not allow your program the memory it needs.

While, yes, it is possible for an administrator to increase quotas, that has consequences as well.     If you don't have administrative access, you need to convince an administrator to increase those quotas (which isn't necessarily easy unless your machine only has one user).   A program that consumes a large amount of memory can cause other programs to be starved of memory - which becomes a problem if those other programs are needed by yourself or other people.   In extreme cases, your program can starve the operating system itself of resources, which causes it and all programs it hosts to slow down, and compromises system stability.    These sort of concerns are why systems enforce quotas in the first place - often by default.

There are also problems that can arise because operating systems can be configured to over-commit.  Loosely speaking, this means that when a program requests memory, the operating system tells the program the allocation has succeeded, even if the operating system hasn't allocated it.  Subsequently, when the program USES that memory (typically, writes data to it), the operating system is suddenly required to ACTUALLY make the memory available.    If the operating system cannot do this for any reason, that becomes a problem for the program (which believes it has access to memory, but the operating system prevents access).   This typically results in some error condition affecting program execution (and often results in program termination).   While the problems associated with over-committing can affect any program, the odds are markedly increased when the program allocates larges amount of memory.

Comment: To be fair, the user isn't asking why it's bad to _use_ a large amount of memory, but whether the strategy of allocating but not using (hence not populating the pages) is reasonable. Most of the reasons above don't apply to that case, since the process isn't using any more physical memory or mapped virtual pages versus the alternative that allocates more sparsely. In particular the usual `ulimit` settings aren't going to kick in here, only `ulimit -v` will work and it is quite problematic since it doesn't count the right thing.

Comment: .... except that allocating a 100GB array and only using 10GB of it (which the OP did ask about) would still commit the 100GB.   The OP did not ask about sparse allocation, only sparse usage (using 1 part in 10) of a block allocated by the program.

Comment: In general, on Linux, it does not commit the 100 GB. Pages are committed one-by-one (or possibly in small groups with fault-around for a file mapping) on first access. That's the trick that allows you to allocate an array much bigger than your physical memory plus swap as long as you don't access much of it.